# Query about sync database columns with days of the week

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I'm doing an android studio project and I'm using a SQLite database. In the app I allow the user to Enter their calorie intake for the day.

The database would have corresponding columns to hold the users calorie intake for that day.
Mondays Calorie intake would be saved in the Monday_Cal column.

EDIT: 
The App has two tables in the database; 1 stores the user details, calories needed and the Mon_Cal etc. 2 stores the product details and calories amount. The user selects the product and the calories are added to the total.

For example,

My question is how do make the column in which the Calories are being entered change to match the days

Ex:

When monday is over the Column being selected changes from Monday_Cal to Tuesday_Cal.

My original plan was a simple if statement and I presumed there was something I could call on (Clock or Calender) however I cant find any material or tutorials on the area I think I may be searching the wrong phrase? And if this way is not possible are there any other alternatives.

Comment: why would you not just have `calorie_intake(user_id, date, calories)` ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, I added something to the original post describing how the database is structured.

Comment: i see. that's not the best design choice, i'll explain in an answer

Comment: no theres the username password, gender, height, weight etc. which is used to calculate the recommended daily calories and then the day columns and then the product details are stored in the other table

Comment: yeah thats what i figured.  repeating groups like that in a table are generally to be avoided

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be storing the individual days as fields in the user table. If you're only storing Mon-Sun, then you're limiting yourself to only ever keeping 7 days history per person.

A better solution is to separate the calorie intake into its own table, which is related to the user table, like this:

```
create table calorie_intake(
  user_id integer not null,
  intake_date date,
  calories integer,
  primary key(user_id, intake_date),
  foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
);
```

This schema uses the `id` field of the `users` table to create a relationship. To find a users calorie intake for a specific day you would then execute a query similar to the following:

```
select calories
  from users u
    inner join calorie_intake i
      on u.id = i.user_id
    where u.id = 1
      and intake_date = '2015-04-10';
```

which would give you the calorie intake for user with id `1`, on April 10th, 2015.

This process of creating relationships and moving away from the 'all data in one table' design is called normalisation, there is plenty of info out there on the subject and if you are going to be doing any database work at all, you are shooting yourself in the foot not being aware of the concept. [heres a link to get started](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/283878)

Answer (score 0):

So something along these lines

Databasehandler:

```
//DATABASE NAME
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AppDatabase";
//USER TABLE
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "Users_Table";
private static final String KEY_U_ID = "User_ID";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "Username";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "Age";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
private static final String KEY_GENDER = "Gender";
private static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "Height";
private static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "Weight";
private static final String KEY_BMI = "BMI";
private static final String KEY_BMR = "BMR";

//PRODUCT TABLE
private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "Products_Table";
private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_ID = "Product_ID";
private static final String KEY_ITEMNAME = "Item_name";
private static final String KEY_ITEMCALORIES = "Item_Calories";

//CALORIEINTAKE TABLE
private static final String TABLE_CALORIE_INTAKE = "CalorieIntake_Table";
private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "USER_ID";
private static final String KEY_INTAKE_DATE = "Intake_Date";
private static final String KEY_CALORIES = "Calories";


//
private static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "( "
        + KEY_U_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_AGE + " INTEGER, "
        + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_HEIGHT + " DOUBLE, "
        + KEY_WEIGHT + " DOUBLE, "
        + KEY_BMI + " DOUBLE, "
        + KEY_BMR + " DOUBLE ); ";

private static final String CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "( " + KEY_PRODUCT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_ITEMNAME + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_ITEMCALORIES + " DOUBLE );";

private static final String CREATE_CALORIE_INTAKE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CALORIE_INTAKE + " ( " + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_INTAKE_DATE + " DATE, " + KEY_CALORIES + " INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY( " + KEY_USER_ID + ", " + KEY_INTAKE_DATE + " ), FOREIGN KEY ( " 
        + KEY_USER_ID + " ) REFERENCES " + TABLE_USERS + " ( " + KEY_U_ID + " ));";
```

The userintake Query:

```
 public CalorieIntake getuserIntake(int id) {
    CalorieIntake calorieIntake = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projection = {KEY_CALORIES};
    String[] selectionargs = {String.valueOf(id)};
    String selection = KEY_U_ID + " =?";
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS + " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_CALORIE_INTAKE + " ON " + KEY_U_ID + " = " + KEY_USER_ID, projection, selection,
            selectionargs, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        calorieIntake = new CalorieIntake(cursor.getInt(0), null, cursor.getDouble(2));


    }
    return calorieIntake;
}
```